# Multiple Barcode Reader issue with image using Zxing

Tags: barcode, zxing

I am just trying to read the multiple barcode from an image using Zxing library. I have an image which does not have barcode but I am getting the barcode info from that image. can you please let me know the reason why this is happening. below is the result I am getting for an attached image when trying to read the barcode.

> Barcode  >>> 21110115     Type 1 >>> EAN_8

Note:- I have more images which gave me the results even if there is no barcode on it.
please share the valid reason.

thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO4ZK.png)

Comment: *I have an image which does not have barcode but I am getting the barcode info from that image*: please can you elaborate on that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a false-positive. That can happen. The following screenshot shows the location where it was found.
[image: screenshot with a marker for the barcode which was found]

Comment: thanks for your reply but what is false positive and which are the other words or area for which Zxing can get information as barcode even if there are no barocde?

Comment: false positive means that there is a range of black and white pixels that look like a barcode for the scanning algorithm. There is no list of words or areas. It happens more or less randomly when a sequence of letters or similar leads to a black and white pattern which can be interpreted as a barcode.

Comment: ok cool. thanks Michael! got the idea now.